# Laravel ardent with authenticatable user model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

May be simple question, but still I don't understand the concept behind it,

I should use,

```
use LaravelArdent\Ardent\Ardent;

class User extends Ardent {}
```

with `Authenticatable` class, now I have like this `class User extends Authenticatable {}`

How can I achieve this together?

Answer (score 0):

Since the current version of Ardent doesn't provide any traits and by definition, you cannot have a class that extends two base classes, I would suggest moving the implementation from the Laravel User class (`Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User`) into your model and extending `LaravelArdent\Ardent\Ardent`.

The code below should suffice but it has not been tested:

```
use LaravelArdent\Ardent\Ardent;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Ardent implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```